# Import MS Access to CSV on Mac programmatically

Tags: ms-access, csv, export, migrate

The [Official Cohort Default Rates for Schools site](http://www2.ed.gov/offices/OSFAP/defaultmanagement/cdr.html) has a link on the left to “Download Entire List.” That downloads an Access database file (.accdb). I'd like to have it in CSV (.csv) format.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453180/importing-ms-access-db-to-mysql/1453193#1453193) provides a [Windows solution to import Access to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php), but ideally, I'd like to have a Unix command-line program, e.g., `accdb2csv input.accdb output.csv`. Is there anything like that? If not, how do I code that?

Here are some other links I've found:

- http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/akaihola/mdb2django
- https://github.com/karlbennett/export-accessdb/blob/5b492778439c85f15d5c859a27094514f7aba8ee/src/main/java/org/youthnet/export/Smasher.java
- https://github.com/Tomvb62/DBConvert/blob/dc67a3d835a9708320d29b8040ddc5cde7e7fa39/src/dbengine/export/MSAccess.java

Comment: Lots of nice research.  What's the question?

Comment: @S.Lott [How do I] Import MS Access to CSV on Mac programmatically?

Comment: @Keng: The answer is in all the research.  I don't get what the question is after piling up all the research.  Are we supposed to answer that question with "read the stuff you found"?  Or "read the stuff you found and write a program"?  There isn't much more we can do except actually write the code.  Unless there's a question.

Comment: Can't you find a Windows PC with A2007/A2010 and open the ACCDB and export to CSV? Is this something you need to do repeatedly? If so, you really should complain about them providing it in such a proprietary format. Jet/ACE doesn't run on anything other than Windows, and I don't know if an of the Linux projects to reverse engineer Jet can deal with ACCDBs. In short, I strongly doubt you can do what you want. But I still think it's completely wrong of them to provide only ACCDB format for download.

Answer (score 1):

I just released an access2csv program based on Jackess. Code is at https://github.com/AccelerationNet/access2csv, a binary is available at https://github.com/AccelerationNet/access2csv/releases.

Answer (score 0):

so right click rename the file from Aaron.accdb to Aaron.zip and then right click unzip it. Office 2007 / 2010 formats are effectively zipped XML files.

This will give you a bunch of XML that you can easily parse using Excel, or XSL, etc.