# ms access dump into sql insert

Tags: database, ms-access

Is there a way in which i can dump a fairly large ms access db into an INSERT INTO TABLE format to a file. I would like to do this for all tables in my db.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Insert into what? Can you explain more clearly where you are at the moment and where you want to end up?

Answer (score 0):

taking a look at this might help you.

[Importing MS ACCESS DB to mySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453180/importing-ms-access-db-to-mysql)

Alternatively, you can export your MS Access Database into CSV, and use PHP or mySQL Query to insert the csv into the mySQL database.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE `report` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```